# How to redirect local hotspot traffic to webserver

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, wifi-hotspot, web-server

I want to redirect all incoming traffic in my android shared hotspot to my local webserver (192.168.43.1:8080), so if anybody connected to me put any url like "www.google.com" will automatically be redirect to "192.168.43.1:8080", **I do have root access**, what should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is called session hijacking.

There is a penetration testing suite called [D-sploit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSploit) that can do the feature you are requesting about. You can search dsploit apk files on the internet as they are no longer updated.

Recently, **Dsploit** has merged with [**Zanti**](https://www.zimperium.com/zanti-mobile-penetration-testing), you can try any of these.

- Keep in mind that these are just for analysing security issues of your network, but involving in a fraudulent activity with other users will make you liable for your actions, so use wisely.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is called captive portal. On android this can be done by loading our own configuration file for dnsmasq. I made an a minimal UI app for this purpose. You can find it on XDA : https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/guide-setup-fake-captive-portal-android-t4011689
If you are android developer, please help us to improve the app.

And also this app requires root permission.